# Spring MVC/Freemarker: using a message from a bundle in a Freemarker expression

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, freemarker

In a Fremarker template I need to access a message taken from an i18n resource bundle provided by Spring MVC inside a Freemarker expression.

I have already imported the Spring macros from `spring.ftl` and I can use the messages with the following macro:

```
<@spring.messageText "my.key" "Default message" />
```

But actually I'm not able to access messages from inside expressions, such as in built ins:

```
${myBoolean?string( ###here I want my true message###, ###here I want my false message###)}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the concrete case you show, maybe you should just write

```
<#if myBoolean><@spring.messageText ...><#else><@spring.messageText ...></#if>
```

and if it's needed often, then make a `#macro` for it.

In the more generic case, the problem is that you can't call a macro (or directive) from an expression, and Spring should offer a function variation of `message` too. I don't know Spring MVC, but looking at `spring.ftl`, it seems that `springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code, text)` should work for that. But that's quite verbose, so probably you want to create a `/lib/springutils.ftl` with content like:

```
<#function message code text=''>
    <#if text != ''>
        <#return springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code, text)>
    <#else>
        <#return springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(code)>
    </#if>
</#function>
```

and then in your templates:

```
<#import "/lib/springutils.ftl" as su>

${myBoolean?string(su.message(...), su.message(...))}
```

But, beware, if you print a value with `${...}`, it's effected by `#escape` (if you use that, of course), while if you print something with `<@...>`, it's never escaped (as `<@...>`/`<#...>` meant to print markup). So if your message contains HTML, with `${...}` you may end up showing the HTML markup literally for the user (as `<` will be escaped to `&lt;` and so on). Unless, you write `<#noescape>${...}</#noescape>`.

(Update to escaping: FreeMarker 2.3.24 supports automatic escaping without `#escape`, and there you would use `${su.message(...)?no_esc}`. Even better, if you somehow know inside the `message` function that the message is HTML, you can use `<#return springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(...)?no_esc>`, and then just write `${su.message(...)}` and FreeMarker will not double-escape it.)

Comment: Thank you! Very complete answer.